# Select where first letter in a range ( PostgreSQL )

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to select from a table where word's first letter is in a range (a-f for example)

I tried with a where clause like this:

> WHERE lower(substring(title from 1 for 1)) IN ARRAY['a', 'k', 't']

hoping that I will find a way to generate the range ARRAY dynamically later.

The above is not working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [SIMILAR TO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html) keyword. The following will match all titles that start with either 'a', 'k', or 't'.

```
... WHERE lower(title) SIMILAR TO '(a|k|t)%'
```

If you want to use a range, you could use the `[]` notation:

```
... WHERE lower(title) SIMILAR TO '[a-f]%'
```

**NOTES**

1. The `%` character matches any number of characters following the pattern. For instance, the second pattern example would match:  'abc', 'ab', 'a', 'far', 'fear' etc.
2. Also, it is important to note that the `SIMILAR TO` keyword is only available to PostgreSQL and it is not ANSI SQL.
3. Finally, the `lower(title)` is not necessary when using the character class. You could simply search for something like

   `WHERE title SIMILAR TO '[a-fA-F]%'`

Answer (score 6):

`IN` doesn't understand an array on the right side, you want `= ANY`:

```
WHERE lower(substring(title from 1 for 1)) = ANY (ARRAY['a', 'k', 't'])
```

Or you could use [`LIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE), [`SIMILAR TO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP), or [`~` (POSIX regex)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE).

Extra references:

- [Subquery Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html)
- [Row and Array Comparisons](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html)